# I need a code to copy specific data from daily-updated excel workbook to my main excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a main excel workbook (1) with many tables but contains same columns as;
productnumber________name_______surname_______price

```
                                                     xxx
```

Have another workbook (2) which contains columns as;
productnumber________city_______company_______price

What I have tried?

I have 10000 products in workbook 1, 500 products in workbook 2, so if i use VLOOKUP function on (xxx) cell by looking up the "productnumber" in other sheet, I get "Na" error in some of the cells due to a lack of enough productnumber in daily updated workbook (2)

Second workbook (2) is being updated everyday and I just want to copy and paste the daily prices to my main workbook (1) and

what is the shortest way to do it? How can I use VBA to do that? Which code would help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Short of having enough information about the names of your objects, try adapting this working code to your names:

```
Sub refreshPrices()
    Dim cel As Range, wbNewPrices As Workbook, v
    Set wbNewPrices = Workbooks.Open("C:\SO\newPrices.xlsm")
    For Each cel In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("Table1[productnumber]")
        v = Application.VLookup(cel.value, wbNewPrices.Sheets(1).Range("Table1"), 4, 0)
        If Not IsError(v) Then cel.Offset(, 3).value = v
    Next
    wbNewPrices.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I am giving more information, 

My main workbook name: SPREAD ve HEDEFLER-BSs.xlsx
worksheet is "2017"
have many tables with same column letters(there are only few blank rows between tables)
 

Product number workbook name: KULLANILABILIRFACTORINGBAKIYELERIOZET-03 03 2017.xls
worksheet is "Sheet1"
Have 1 table and starts from b2 to h10000

The date is changing everyday in second workbook name.